# Creating an array of layouts

Tags: android, resources, android-resources

I have an array in resources:

```
<integer-array name="my_layouts_array">
    <item>@layout/layout1</item>
    <item>@layout/layout2</item>
    <item>@layout/layout3</item>
    ...
    <item>@layout/layoutn</item>
</integer-array>
```

Eclipse can move me from this file to selected layout on Ctrl+Click.

When I'm accessing this array from code

```
getResources().getIntArray(R.array.my_layouts_array);
```

it returns me an array of size `n`, but containing only zeros.

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a TypedArray, an xml array designed to hold an array of resource objects, rather than an integer array.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#TypedArray